# create-react-app to React in Spring - Should I / Can i delete the node modules?

Tags: java, spring, reactjs, spring-boot

so  just as the title says I used create-react-app to create a react application and I coded it on `VSCODE`. Later on I had to add all these files to my spring boot project. I copied all my node modules as well when moving . Do I need the node modules now? or else Can i get rid of them and have only the react specific files like `App.js` ?

Comment: If you get rid of the JS dependencies, how do you expect to actually build and/or serve the React app? Spring can't just serve up App.js.

Comment: yeah sorry, Its just im getting a webpack cofiguration error and i found on github that its resolved if you get rid of the node modules. So i wanted to check if i actually can do that. Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node Modules contain the all the libraries your react app needed. So it is an essential part you cannot delete. If you deleted it react app won't work when you developing the app (using `npm start` command).

To move your react project into Spring you have to build the project
Refer this document - https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/cra-template/template/README.md

It will create a build folder in your react app folder. This build folder contains all the necessary files to run your react project. So when you are deploying the project you only need the files inside this building project. (No need for Node_Modules after building the project)

Next copy your build folder into to `target/classes/public folder` in the Spring project. Then add this plugin to the `pom.xml`

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
                <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <workingDirectory>frontend</workingDirectory>
                    <installDirectory>target</installDirectory>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>install node and npm</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <nodeVersion>v8.9.4</nodeVersion>
                            <npmVersion>5.6.0</npmVersion>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>npm install</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <arguments>install</arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>npm run build</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <arguments>run build</arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

And Add this plugin also

```
<plugin>
   <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
    <execution>
    <phase>generate-resources</phase>
    <configuration>
    <target>
    <copy todir="${project.build.directory}/classes/public">
        <fileset dir="${project.basedir}/frontend/build"/>
    </copy>
    </target>
    </configuration>
    <goals>
        <goal>run</goal>
    </goals>
    </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Build the project and your react project will host inside the Spring project

Here's a link to full React + Spring Project - https://medium.com/@mukundmadhav/build-and-deploy-react-app-with-spring-boot-and-mysql-6f888eb0c600